# Toolbar Editor changed! Miss Editor Area in the Toolbar - ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, toolbar

I have installed ArcGIS Desktop Advanced 10.5.1 but the editor toolbar changed after having a new pc and with the re-instalation of the software ArcGIS. It miss the editor in the tool.

How can I restore the tool or repair the tool?

This image shows how it looks now:

[image]

The image represents how my editor toolbar is, without the `Editor` part. I can't start editing from there but the worst is that I can't stop editing. There isn't another possibility.

This image shows how it should look:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the Editor toolbar:

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/customizing-the-ui/resetting-a-built-in-toolbar.htm

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but it didn't work... unfortunately!! What can I do more??? anyone?

Answer (score 0):

don't know how, after trying many times, the toolbar return to «normal» with this treatment. Thank you very much